# MySQL : Updating a table having a 'where' clause with a max value

Tags: mysql

I want to update the last generated row (the `max(id)` row.

I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
update person t1
set t1.age = 25
where t1.id = (select max(t2.id)  from person t2
            where t2.address = 'LA, California');
```

MySQL tells me that : `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause`

So, I suppose that I cannot reach the same tale while performing operations such as updates.

How can I sole this problem ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as:

```
UPDATE person t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id  FROM person
            WHERE t2.address = 'LA, California') t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.age = 25;
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(t2.id)
INTO @var_max_id
FROM person t2
WHERE t2.address = 'LA, California';

UPDATE person t1
SET t1.age = 25
WHERE t1.id = IFNULL(@var_max_id, -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference the same table in a subquery, but you can instead do it in a JOIN (which is allowed in `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements):

```
UPDATE person a
JOIN   (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM person WHERE address = 'LA, California') b
       ON a.id = b.id
SET    a.age = 25
```

Another way you can do it is by using the `ORDER BY` / `LIMIT` technique:

```
UPDATE   person
SET      age = 25
WHERE    address = 'LA, California'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: the limit 1 method you recommended just simplified my queries so much. very good idea.